# Windows completely destroyed my USB

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, usb

I own a 32GB USB stick. 2 years ago, when I was transferring files from my Windows 7 computer to the aforementioned USB my then computer got completely stuck. I hard reset the computer, and this resulted somehow to the USB being completely "destroyed". What I ment by that, is that in whatever computer I plug it in (I tried 3 different computers), no matter what Operating System is running in (I tried Windows 7/10 and Linux) the USB is not recognized as a valid drive. This is what I get when I try to open the USB:

[windows-error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzRmP.png)

and this is what I get when I try to format the USB:

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCbvB.png)
[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzyIn.png)

I also tried several other third party tools such as [M3 Data Recovery](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/) and [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), but none of those worked either. 
Additionally, I tried to run the following command to an Administrative CMD:

```
chkdsk.exe /x /f J:
```

But this is what I get as a response:

```
The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

I am not interested in the USB's data/files, but to being able use the USB itself. Is there any hope, or I should throw it away ?

Comment: Toss it, they get damaged when disconnected (powered down) during a write operation

Comment: If you run “diskpart”, and type “list disk” what does this return?

Answer (score 1):

There is some discussion of similar issues in the FAQ at Rufus, including an option in the utility to show drives which are not detected:

https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_how_do_I_restore_my_USB_to_how_it_was_before_I_created_a_bootable_drive